# Cannot Click the button by using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I try to click the hidden button by scrolling to the element but still not working. Only if i scroll it manually, the coding is working. May I know the reasons? Thank you! 
website: https://www1.hkexnews.hk/search/titlesearch.xhtml?lang=en

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/Ivan.Chak/Desktop/cbbc/chromedriver", chrome_options=options)
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get("https://www1.hkexnews.hk/search/titlesearch.xhtml?lang=en")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#tier1-select .combobox-input-wrap").click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".searchType .droplist-item:nth-child(2) > a").click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#rbAfter2006 .combobox-field").click()
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Debt and Structured Products')]")
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
time.sleep(1)
element.click()  <--- This is not working!!!
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ElementNotInteractableException           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-323-cf25f85114ab> in <module>()
----> 1 element.click()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py in click(self)
     78     def click(self):
     79         """Clicks the element."""
---> 80         self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
     81 
     82     def submit(self):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py in _execute(self, command, params)
    631             params = {}
    632         params['id'] = self._id
--> 633         return self._parent.execute(command, params)
    634 
    635     def find_element(self, by=By.ID, value=None):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    319         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    320         if response:
--> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    323                 response.get('value', None))

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.142)
```

Comment: Post your error

Comment: Have no error actually. Just keep loading and cannot click the button. But If i manually scroll the box, it will work again.

Comment: If I wait for a longer time, it would have this error,  "ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.142)"

Comment: However, If i manually scroll the box, it will be working again.

Comment: Is it possible that the element is only loaded once you scroll down? So telling Selenium to scroll towards it is not possible. Maybe you can scroll to another element or just down?

Comment: Acutally, I try to use "driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)" to scroll. Although, it can click the button with no error, it did not show the expected result after clicking.

Comment: Also Only if i scroll it manually, the expected result will come out correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible you are scrolling to the element(button) . Which again is getting hidden if your webpage have any kind of ribbon. Try scrolling to any other element above it. This had solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to scroll to the each menu item before click, for that you can use JavaScript `arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);`

You can use general method to scroll before click like in code below:

```
def click(element):
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)
    element.click()


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www1.hkexnews.hk/search/titlesearch.xhtml?lang=en")

driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".searchType").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='droplist-item' and ./a[.='Headline Category']]").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("rbAfter2006").click()

click(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[.='Debt and Structured Products']"))
click(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[.='Debt Securities']"))
click(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[.='Issuer-Specific Report - Debt Securities']"))
```

Or you can use specific method for menu selection like below:

```
def select_menu(menu_text):
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//a[.='{menu_text}']")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)
    element.click()


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www1.hkexnews.hk/search/titlesearch.xhtml?lang=en")

driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".searchType").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='droplist-item' and ./a[.='Headline Category']]").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("rbAfter2006").click()

select_menu("Debt and Structured Products")
select_menu("Debt Securities")
select_menu("Issuer-Specific Report - Debt Securities")
```

More generic method to select search criterias:

```
def select_search_criteria(criteria, *menus):
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".searchType").click()
    criteria_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//div[@class='droplist-item' and ./a[.='{criteria}']]")
    data_value = criteria_element.get_attribute("data-value")
    criteria_element.click()

    document_type_element = driver.find_element_by_id(data_value)
    if document_type_element.find_element_by_css_selector("a.combobox-field").get_attribute("aria-expanded") == "false":
        document_type_element.click()

    for menu in menus:
        element = document_type_element.find_element_by_xpath(f".//a[.='{menu}']")
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)
        element.click()


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www1.hkexnews.hk/search/titlesearch.xhtml?lang=en")

select_search_type("Headline Category", "Debt and Structured Products", "Debt Securities")
select_search_type("Document Type", "Circulars")
```